# URL works when append #

Tags: java, angular, url, azure-devops, url-routing

I have a url which is not working when i tried hitting it directly, but it works when I append /# to the url.

But for QA when I hit the url it is working where it automatically adding the /# and goes to required login page. In QA it was manually deployed not through VSTS pipeline

- Actual url(not Working): `https://<applicationurl>.azurewebsites.net`
- URL(working one): `https://<applicationurl>.azurewebsites.net/#`

Deployment: VSTS build and release

Hosting: Azure App Service

Application: Java, Angular6

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

In Java a URI of the form "http://x.y.z" has a null path.
A URI of the form "http://x.y.z/" has an absolute path which is "/".

Some browsers will automatically correct an URL by appending "/" if the URL does not have a path, but programmatic interfaces and servers may not.

I suspect that what you describe is just a user error - you need to make sure the input URL has a path. This is what happens when you append "/#" - but I don't think the # makes any difference (that's just adding an empty fragment).